# Relative pathnames working differently on Safari and Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, safari

I'm finding that relative path names in HTML are working differently in Safari (14.0.3) and Chrome (88.0.4324.96) on my MacBook.

If I have all the files in one place (see below), everything is fine, both in Safari and Chrome.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

    <!-- the style sheet is local -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style_sheet.css" />

    <title>HTML 101 - title A</title>

</head>

<body>
    <p>This is a line of HTML - page A</p>
    <! -- let's have a local picture -->
    <img src="yellow.jpg" alt="Welcome!">
</body>

</html>
```

But I want the HTML and pictures to be in different places. Suppose I have an 'html' directory and an 'images' directory, with a style sheet one level above. (See below.) This works fine in Chrome, but in Safari, the style sheet is not picked up, and the image is not displayed.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<!-- let's start at the very beginning -->
<head>

    <!-- the style sheet is one level above -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../style_sheet.css" />

    <title>HTML 101 - title B</title>

</head>

<body>
    <p>This is a line of HTML - page B</p>
    <!-- the image file is in a sibling folder -->
    <img src="../images/yellow.jpg" alt="Welcome!">
</body>

</html>
```

How do relative pathnames work in HTML in Safari?

Comment: verify you are not cached.After that look at the network requests and see what is happening.

Comment: Should have said - maybe this is relevant - this is all implemented on my MacBook hard drive, so not sure if network requests are relevant. I'm clearing the cache, and investigating further...

Comment: running off file protocol and not a local server also has different rules. It is good practice to run a local server if you are developing webpages.

Comment: Understood, but these pages are not required to be visible on anything but my laptop; they exist as a scrapbook, especially of my photo collection, where I have a page per photo, with the appropriate 'previous' and 'next' links, and explanatory text.

Comment: To the original point, clearing the cache has fixed the problem; many thanks.